# How to remove the space after the slash when year and original year were reported in Bibtex with Mathpazo font

Tags: bibtex, apa-style, mathpazo

When referring to Goffman (1959/1969), I see a space after the slash (-> Goffman (1959/ 1969). Can anyone help me removing this space after the slash? I am using the mathpazo font; therefore I have added an additional line into my MWE.

Here my MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
\usepackage[osf,sc]{mathpazo} %The font I used in my document 
\author{XX} \title{YYY}

\begin{document} 
\maketitle 
\citep{Example1}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{test} 
\end{document}
```

The bib-file (test.bib) contains the following entry:

```
@book{Example1,
   author = {Goffman, Erving},
   title = {{Wir spielen alle Theater: Die Selbstdarstellung im Alltag}},
   publisher = {Piper Verlag GmbH},
   address = {(Weber-Schäfer, P., Übers.). München},
   year = {1969},
   originalyear={1959},
}
```

Comment: I don't get a space.

Comment: Update: I am using the mathpazo font and have updated my MWE. There is a space after the slash, which I wanted to remove or even minimize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no space. It's just an unfortunate combination of shapes; there should be a kern between `/` and `1`, but the font doesn't provide it. You can work around this unfortunate state of affairs with the following trick.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Example1,
   author = {Goffman, Erving},
   title = {{Wir spielen alle Theater: Die Selbstdarstellung im Alltag}},
   publisher = {Piper Verlag GmbH},
   address = {(Weber-Schäfer, P., Übers.). München},
   year = {1969},
   originalyear={1959},
}
@article{Example2,
  author={A B},
  title={T},
  journal={J},
  year=2000,
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
\usepackage[osf,sc]{mathpazo} %The font I used in my document

\makeatletter % <--- Here starts the trick
\def\APACyear#1{\split@APACyear#1//\@nil}
\def\split@APACyear#1/#2/#3\@nil{%
  #1\if!#2!\else/\negthinspace#2\fi
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\author{XX} \title{YYY}

\maketitle
\citep{Example1}, \citep{Example2}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

I redefine the `\APACyear` command to look for a `/` in its argument and, in this case, add `\negthinspace` after the slash. If you don't have years starting by 2 there should not be problems. The `Example2` entry has been added just for checking that a missing original year doesn't cause problems; the `filecontents*` trick is just to make the example selfcontained, use your own `.bib` file.

[image]

Comment: Great! Your solution works fine! Thank you!